# My custom css is not working when using bootstrap for a wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, themes

I am just learning Wordpress development and am building a theme. I use bootstrap and my own custom css. I know custom files are to be declared AFTER bootstrap, but this hasn't gotten my css going.

My function's code:

```php
<?php 

function smartwp_remove_wp_block_library_css(){
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-block-library-theme' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-block-style' ); // Remove WooCommerce block CSS
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'smartwp_remove_wp_block_library_css', 100 );

function load_stylesheets() {
wp_register_style('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css',
array(),false,'all');
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');

wp_register_style('style',get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
array(),false,'all');
wp_enqueue_style('style');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');

function loadjs() {
wp_register_script('customjs',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js','',true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'customjs');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','loadjs');
```

You see I tried also some code I found on the net to disable Guttenberg css, but to no effect. I see from the console that my style.css is included and I see bootstrap working.

My css isn't much yet:

```css
   /*
Theme name: 
Author: 
*/

body {
  background: "#ff03ab";
}
```

I must be doing something wrong, typos maybe? Also tried clearing browser history, and variety of css elements in my style.css

Comment: use the different ```class name``` and use ```important!``` for your custom CSS.

Comment: I guess you should skip the `" "` around the color code

Comment: As always, it's the rookie mistake. Removing "" helped, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the custom CSS file is loaded after bootstrap, you have to add bootstrap as a dependency in `wp_register_style()`:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/

```php
wp_register_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'bootstrap' ), false, 'all' );
```